# How do all the short stories and graphic novels fit into the Rivers of London Timeline?

Tags: suggested-order, chronological-order, rivers-of-london

What is the suggested reading order for all the Rivers of London material? Where do the short stories from [Tales from the Folly](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/54289642-tales-from-the-folly) fit in chronologically?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Handily the Author maintains as chronology page, which you can find [here](https://www.benaaronovitch.com/chronology/).

This falls downs a little for a reading order however, by putting the flashback [Action at a Distance](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/41140896-rivers-of-london-volume-7) graphic novel and the earliest short stories from [Tales from the Folly](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/54289642-tales-from-the-folly) right at the start, when they make a lot more sense later on.

A more limited view, from the front of the latest graphic novel shows everything published to that point, without the short stories. As previously stated, Action at a Distance would probably be better read directly after Lies Sleeping, rather than as a starting point for the series.

[image: Graphical Illustration of timeline]

In case of dead-links and to shuffle the most jarring flashback stories to a more comfortable place a full reading order as of July 2023 is below;

- Rivers Of London
- The Home Crowd Advantage (Tales From The Folly)
- Tobias Winter (Tales From The Folly)
- Moon Over Soho
- The Domestic (Tales From The Folly)
- Whispers Underground
- The Cockpit (Tales From The Folly)
- Broken Homes
- Body Work (Graphic Novel)
- Foxglove Summer
- What Abigail Did That Summer (Novella)
- The Loneliness Of The Long Distance Granny (Tales From The Folly)
- Night Witch (Graphic Novel)
- Favourite Uncle (Tales From The Folly)
- Black Mould (Graphic Novel)
- King Of The Rats (Tales From The Folly)
- The Furthest Station (Novella)
- Detective Stories (Graphic Novel)
- Reynolds (Tales From The Folly)
- Cry Fox (Graphic Novel)
- Waterweed (Graphic Novel)
- The Hanging Tree
- A Rare Book Of Cunning Device (Tales From The Folly)
- The October Man (Novella)
- Lies Sleeping
- Three Rivers, Two Husbands And A Baby (Tales From The Folly)
- Action At A Distance (Graphic Novel)
- Nightingale: London 1966 (Tales From The Folly)
- Dedicated Follower Of Fashion (Tales From The Folly)
- The Fey And The Furious (Graphic Novel)
- False Value
- Vanessa Sommers Other Christmas List (Tales From The Folly)
- Among Our Weapons
- Monday Monday (Graphic Novel)
- Deadly Ever After (Graphic Novel)

** Winter's Gifts is the most recently published Novella, it doesn't currently appear on the Author's chronology, or Titan Comics' page. It is mentioned as taking place in January 2015, and probably takes place before Cry Fox. There's a Fan Wiki [timeline](https://follypedia.fandom.com/wiki/Timeline)  available, with solid details, but some if it contradicts the list on the Author's site. Possibly this comes back to framing sequences and the events within the story.

Comment: This order (particularly the way Takes from the Folly is interleaved just so) is going to make checking out books from the library awkward! Can you get away without that?

Comment: Yes - reading in publication order is perfectly fine; some of the short stories get mentioned in the novels, but you can treat them as noodle incidents and not miss out on anything critical.

Comment: @AncientSwordRage totally agree with Michael, but the original question was about chronology rather than reading order. Reading order wise, spoiler safety suggests reading the whole of Tales from the Folly after False Value, but they are all fairly disconnected shorts. And I should probably look to update this soon with the more recent additions.

Comment: @Jontia let me know if you plan any more updates before the bounty is up

Comment: @AncientSwordRage I'm all done for now. I think there is probably a lot of good info on the linked fan wiki, but more in depth than I want to get into for now.

Comment: @jontia way more than I need! I'm wondering if another question about which of the minor stories is *needed* for the main series. For instance Lies Sleeping references Black mould, and haunted BMWs which aren't needed but I've just started false value and I can't shake I should know who Jacob is etc.

Comment: @AncientSwordRage the start of False Value is written non-chronologically. Jacob has not appeared in the series before.